# How can I map array in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, anime.js, vue-composition-api

I'm working with a code using Vue and `anime.js`. I find my code is too long, consisting of 1500+ lines. I cut my `sampleText` to 5 items here so Stack Overflow would accept my question, but it's actually 114 items.

Also how can I randomly place the `sampleText` into `<li>`? It should shuffle `sampleText` in each `<li>` position.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        {{ texts.text1 }}
      </li>
      <li">
        {{ texts.text2 }}
      </li>
      <li>
        {{ texts.text3 }}
      </li>
      <li>
        {{ texts.text4 }}
      </li>
      <li>
        {{ texts.text5 }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import anime from 'animejs/lib/anime.es.js'
import { reactive, onMounted } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'

const sampleText1 = 'インバウント'
const sampleText2 = 'BtoB'
const sampleText3 = 'セールス'
const sampleText4 = 'OODA'
const sampleText5 = '指標'

const characters =
  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
const charactersLength = characters.length

export default {
  layout: 'default',
  data() {
    return {
      sam1: sampleText1,
      sam2: sampleText2,
      sam3: sampleText3,
      sam4: sampleText4,
      sam5: sampleText5,
    }
  },
  setup() {
    const texts = reactive({
      text1: sampleText1,
      text2: sampleText2,
      text3: sampleText3,
      text4: sampleText4,
      text5: sampleText5,
    })

    const scrambleText = (text, name) => ({ progress }) => {
      if (Math.floor(progress) <= 50) {
        if (Math.floor(progress) >= 50) {
          texts[name] = text
        } else if (Math.floor(progress) % 5 === 0) {
          texts[name] = text.replace(/./g, () =>
            characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength))
          )
        }
      }
    }

    onMounted(() => {
      anime({
        targets: '.main',
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        loop: true,
        update: scrambleText(sampleText1, 'text1'),
      })
      anime({
        targets: '.main',
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        loop: true,
        update: scrambleText(sampleText2, 'text2'),
      })
      anime({
        targets: '.main',
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        loop: true,
        update: scrambleText(sampleText3, 'text3'),
      })
      anime({
        targets: '.main',
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        loop: true,
        update: scrambleText(sampleText4, 'text4'),
      })
      anime({
        targets: '.main',
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        loop: true,
        update: scrambleText(sampleText5, 'text5'),
      })
    })

    return {
      texts,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a good use case for arrays and loops.

1. Instead of an object, put your sample text into an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), and iterate that with a [`for`-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).
2. Update `scrambleText()` call to pass the array index instead of the object key previously used for your object:

```js
const texts = reactive([ // 1️⃣
  'インバウント',
  'BtoB',
  'セールス',
  'OODA',
  '指標',
  //...
])

onMounted(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) { // 1️⃣
    anime({
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'linear',
      loop: true,
      update: scrambleText(texts[i], i), // 2️⃣
    })
  }
})
```

3. In your template, use a [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for) to iterate the `texts` array:

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="text in texts">{{ text }}</li>
</ul>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/iterating-a-large-array-14321?file=/src/components/MyList.vue)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for thiss. But why the anime.js is not working for me? Why is that?

Comment: Also since its 114 items, how can I just show only 12 items per **ul**?

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your texts in an array and iterate over it like so:

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="text in texts" :key="text">{{ text }}</li>
</ul>
```

Key given with the condition that all of your texts are unique.

And follow up with changing the functions in the `onMounted` to do something like:

```
texts.forEach((text, index) => {
      anime({
        targets: ".main",
        duration: 1000,
        easing: "linear",
        loop: true,
        update: scrambleText(text, index),
      });
    });
```

Comment: Your usage of `scrambleText` assumes the original object instead of an array that you initially suggest. The second argument should be `index` if `texts` is an array.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your helpp. But an error occurred and it says **TypeError: texts.forEach is not a function**

Comment: Is there any changes should be done to the items?

`const sampleText1 = 'インバウント'
const sampleText2 = 'BtoB'
const sampleText3 = 'セールス'
const sampleText4 = 'OODA'
const sampleText5 = '指標'

  data() {
    return {
      sam1: sampleText1,
      sam2: sampleText2,
      sam3: sampleText3,
      sam4: sampleText4,
      sam5: sampleText5,
    }
  },
  setup() {
    const texts = reactive({
      text1: sampleText1,
      text2: sampleText2,
      text3: sampleText3,
      text4: sampleText4,
      text5: sampleText5,
    })`

Comment: I may not have understood the scramble function... I put this up very quickly in codesandbox and use `this.` instead of `reactive`: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-pond-6mmtg?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue